# bcd path dual boot Windows/ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7, paths, ubuntu-studio

Liking ubuntu (studio), but I do not like how grub takes over the boot process.

had a dual boot and reformatted the Windows partition. Reinstalled Windows.

have a bcd program on Windows to dual boot, but do not know how to find the path to boot the ubuntu.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though your grub did not install properly or became corrupted.  Please try this [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD) solution.

Comment: No, it's just a pain if you want to modify Windows, or rearrange some things.